# Find all positive integer solutions $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy $5^x \cdot 7^y +4= 3^z$?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

This is another contest math-problem.

The only problem that I cannot find the way to tackle this problem.

Can anybody try to provide the solution to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please check that the equation is the all right now? And by the way you can check some LaTEX tutorials to make things look better

Comment: @Stefan4024,yes the equation is right. Sorry for the bad writing, Stefan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$ we get that $5|5^x7^y$, so we have: $3^z \equiv 4 \mod 5$. Since $ord_5(3) = 4$ and $3^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ we get $\fbox{$z = 4n + 2$}$. Obviously $z$ is even so we have $\fbox{$z=2k$}$. Then we have:

$$5^x7^y = 3^{2k} - 4 = (3^k - 4)(3^k + 4)$$

Now let $d = (3^k - 4,3^k + 4)$, then $d$ divides their diference, so $d\mid 8$. But both numbers are obviously odd, hence $(3^k - 4,3^k + 4) = 1$. Since we have 2 different prime factors on the left side we have $4$ cases:

**Case 1:**

\begin{cases} 3^k - 4 = 5^x \\ 3^k + 4 = 7^y \end{cases}

Working wrt modulo 5 and 7 respectively we get $k=4n + 2$ and $k=6n + 1$, an obvious contradiction.

**Case 2:**

\begin{cases} 3^k + 4 = 5^x \\ 3^k - 4 = 7^y \end{cases}

Working modulo $3$ we get: $5^x \equiv 2^x \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \implies \fbox{$x=2m$}$

So we get: $3^k = (5^m - 2)(5^m + 2)$. As previously we get that the two factors on the right side are comprime. Since $5^m + 2 > 1$ we get that the only possibilty is:

\begin{cases} 5^m - 2 = 1 \\ 5^m + 2 = 3^k \end{cases}

For the first equation we have: $5^m = 3$ a contradiction.

**Case 3:**

\begin{cases} 3^k + 4 = 1 \\ 3^k - 4 = 5^x7^y \end{cases}

An obvious contradiction for the first equation.

**Case 4:**

\begin{cases} 3^k + 4 = 5^x7^y \\ 3^k - 4 = 1 \end{cases}

From the second equation we get $3^k = 5$ a contradiction, because $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Hence this equation doesn't have a solution in $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: You have a sign error in $3^z \equiv -4 \mod 5$. Also, you reused the name $k$ in case 1.

Comment: @Stefan4024, I can only find (x,y,z)= (1,0,2) as the solution. But, I cannot find the other, how can I get the other solution by using your method? thanks

Comment: As much as I know 0 isn't a positive integer. If you want to include 0, then my approach prove that if we have solution then at least on of the exponents is 0. And the rest should not be too difficult. Can you do that on your own?

Comment: oh, yes, i forgot that 0 is not a positive integer. So, based on your 4 cases, can we conclude that this problem didn't have a solution, @Stefan4024 ? thanks

Comment: Yes, this equation doens't have a solution in positive integers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Considering the equation modulo $5$ shows that $z = 2+4m$ for some integer $m$. Considering the equation modulo $7$ shows that $z = 4 + 6n$ for some integer $n$. Thus we have $2 + 4m = 4 + 6n$. This is a [linear Diophantine equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation), and the solutions to the original equation may be found by first solving this.

Edit: I seem to have overlooked the fact that the linear diophantine equation reads $2m - 3n = 1$. Because of the negative sign, there are infinitely many positive solutions and thus this attack method does not seem to help.

Comment: Hey there :) I know a tiny bit about polynomial residues, but I am really surprised to see that exponentiation can be just as powerfully (and simply) worked. I can see how you could reduce something like 7^{n} mod 5 to 2^{n} mod 5, but then, how would you proceed in studying the behavior? I am surprised you made it so simple because I thought that studying exponentiation under a modulus is inherently a computationally difficult task to do (cryptography etc.). Sorry, I know very little about maths, but could you explain your methods a bit or lead me to a good source on this :)? Thanks!

Comment: Minor correction, you should have gotten $z = 2+4m$ and $z = 4+6n$

Comment: Doh! Of course, thanks @JimmyK4542. The exponent is modulo the order of the multiplicative group, not the additive group! Silly mistake.

Comment: @Just_a_fool: Remember that something like $5 \cdot 7^y$ is always zero modulo 5. So for example, modulo 5 the equation reads $-1 = 3^z$. By writing out $z=1,2,3...$, see if you can figure out what's going on.

Comment: @rghthndsd Thanks. whoops… I see I performed the classic case of not sincerely trying a question before asking! :p

Answer (score 0):

Given; $5^x \cdot 7^y +4= 3^z$ 
we get, $(-1)^x +1 \equiv 0 \pmod3$ hence $x$ must be odd, again, $(-1)^y \equiv (-1)^z \pmod 4$ hence $y$ and $z$ have the same parity.  Again $-1 \equiv 3^z \pmod 5$ or $1 \equiv 3^{2z} \pmod 5$ hence by Euler-Fermat theorem $2|z$. Again since $y$ and $z$ are even we have, $5^x \equiv 4 \pmod 8$, since $x$ is odd, we have two cases; either $x=4k+1$ or $x=4k+3$, note that $5^{4k} \equiv 1 \pmod 8$, the two cases each yield $5^x \equiv 5 \pmod 8$ a contradiction, hence $x$ cannot be greater than $0$, i.e $x=0$. The given equation then becomes $7^{2m} +4= 3^{2n}$ or $(7^m)^2 +2^2= (3^n)^2$, a pythagora's equation with solution, $2=2uv$, $7^m=u^2-v^2$ and $3^n=u^2+v^2$ from which it is obvious that $m$ and $n$ do not exist, and hence, $y(=2m)$ and $z(=2n)$ do not exist

Comment: I don't see how you go from $3 \equiv 3^z \pmod 6$ to $2|z-1$. $3 \equiv 3^z \pmod 6$ only tells you that $z > 0$.

Comment: Wait a sec: modulo 8, $7^y$ with an even y is 1. So we get $5^x+4\equiv3^z\pmod8$. Being $z$ even, $3^z\equiv1\pmod8$, since it is $9^{\frac{z}{2}}\equiv1^{\frac{z}{2}}\pmod8$. So $5^x+4\equiv1\pmod8\implies5^x\equiv-3\equiv\fbox{$5$}\pmod8$, not 4. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: So that only gives us $x$ is odd, being that the condition for $5^{x-1}\equiv1\pmod8$, since $5^2=25\equiv1\pmod8$, but we already know that.